# Using mathematica.m files in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: packages

I am not 100% certain that I should ask this question, but I am hoping that some of you had similar issues with the combination `Mathematica` + `Ubuntu` and can provide an answer. If you think that this question is not appropriate for this site, let me know and I will delete it.

I am working on `Ubuntu 20.04` and I want to run something on Docker. This is done quite easily and I can use my terminal and the command

`docker run -v /home/konstantinos/Desktop/bootstrap:/usr/local/share/scalar_blocks wlandry/sdpb:2.4.0 scalar_blocks --dim 3 --order 40 --max-derivs 10 --spin-ranges 0-15 --poles 6 --delta-12 0 --delta-34 0 --num-threads=8 -o/usr/local/share/scalar_blocks --precision=776`

The above is very quick to execute.

The above command creates `.m` files in the folder `bootstrap` that is on my desktop. However, the files appear to be locked. I am attaching a screenshot of the folder

[image]

And actually, if I drag and drop one of these files in the terminal and try to execute it I get the following message

`bash: /home/konstantinos/Desktop/bootstrap/zzbDerivTable-d3-delta12-0-delta34-0-L0-nmax6-keptPoleOrder10-order40.m: Permission denied`

I think that this is the source of my main problem. If you go on this [lecture notes/review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05147) and choose the option `Other Formats` in the Download part of the webpage, you can download the source which contains a mathematica wrapper called `Bootstrap.m`. When I run the notebook `Bootstrap.m` it is supposed to read the files created previously, namely `zzbDerivTable-d3-delta12-0-delta34-0-L0-nmax6-keptPoleOrder10-order40.m` and all others and create some `.XML` files. However, when I run the final command of the notebook, namely

```
Ising["/home/konstantinos/Desktop/bootstrap/test14.XML"][.52,1.4,1.6,6,10,Range[0,15],40]
```

I get

```
/home/konstantinos/Desktop/bootstrap/zzbDerivTable-d3.-delta12-0-delta34-0-L0-nmax6-keptPoleOrder10-order40.m does not exist. Exiting.
```

Any suggestions?

Edit 1: after the comment by @LouisB, I would like to add that the missing period is not the issue. After using the following files, I still get the same error message

[image]

Comment: Notice the period in the file name in the "does not exist" message *... -d3.-delta12- ...*.  The first file in the screenshot does not have the period -- *... -d3-delta12- ...*

Comment: @LouisB thanks for the input. I did notice that, however, I do not think that this is the issue. I went and added the period after I got the error message, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files were originally created by the `docker` group in your linux which is the reason for getting `Permission denied`. If you're a super user, just run the following to restore the ownership:

```
sudo chown -R konstantinos /home/konstantinos/Desktop/bootstrap/*
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot!